# React Native Detox - Run specific test file

Tags: react-native, detox

I am running e2e tests using Detox (https://github.com/wix/Detox) and I was wondering if there is a way to control which test file to run, either through the CLI or some config file.

Currently I am using two test files in the following file structure:

```
> e2e 
 config.json
 environment.js
 firstTest.js
 secondTest.js
```

My .detoxrc.json file below:

```
{
 "testRunner": "jest",
 "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
 "configurations": {
 "android.emu.debug": {
  "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
  "build":
    "cd android && sh gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
  "type": "android.emulator",
  "device": {
    "avdName": "Pixel_2_API_28"
  }
},
"android.emu.release": {
  "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
  "build": "cd android && sh gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && 
   cd ..",
  "type": "android.emulator",
  "device": {
    "avdName": "Pixel_2_API_28"
  }
  }

 }
}
```

When I run the tests using

```
detox test --configuration android.emu.debug
```

firstTest.js runs first and then secondTest.js runs, which is fine.

Sometimes you would not like to run firstTest.js to save time and only run secondTest.js.

So my question is: Is it possible to control which test file to run either through the detox CLI or by modifying the .detoxrc.json file? Or by some other means?

I am not interested in a dummy hack like commenting out all the tests in firstTest.js file or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In e2e folder you have config.json and inside of the config you have testRegex:

```
 "testRegex": "\\.js\\.js$"
```

If you want to run only 1 set/file of tests you can change the name there and give the file name.
Example:

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "./environment",
    "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
    "testTimeout": 120000,
    "testRegex": "firstTest.js.js$",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
```

}

I got your feeling. On other tools you can add flags.
Here are stated some cli flags, but none points to what you want:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DetoxCLI.md

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this from the command line using the "-f filepath" flag:

```
detox test --configuration ios -f e2e/signupTest.e2e.js
```

Comment: I tried this but it always runs all the test files. I am using "detox": "^17.4.4".